# how do I use if condition in cursor because our professor don't allow us use where clause in the select statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

Our question is showing all the countries that have names that are exactly 5 letter long. This is the cursor code and I want add if condition into it.

```
declare
cursor cursor_full is select * from country_cont;
begin
for counter in cursor_full 
loop 
dbms_output.put_line(counter.country|| ' ' || counter.continent);
end loop; 
end;
```

However my professor said that you can't using where clause within the select statement and you should display all the countries and continent.

so i tried this code:

```
declare
country varchar(50);
cursor cursor_full is select * from country_cont;
begin
if length(country)=5 then
for counter in cursor_full 
loop 
dbms_output.put_line(counter.country|| ' ' || counter.continent);
end loop; 
end if;
end;
```

the script output show that PL/SQL procedure successfully completed but nothing return in DBMS output

Hope someone can help me, I spent whole night to think about it,please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `country` doesn't contain any value, it is `null` so `if` condition is never true and `loop` is never executed. Sample data would help; meanwhile, see if this helps.

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select * from country_cont) loop
    if length(cur_r.country) > 5 then
       dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.country|| ' ' || cur_r.continent);
  end loop; 
end;
```

Don't forget to `set serveroutput on`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir it's work in the implicit cursor, but how do I execute it in explicit cursor. For example it's not gonna work if i write code like that way" declare
cursor counterx is select * from country_cont;
begin
for counter in counterx
 loop if length(courterx.country)=5 then
  dbms_output.put_line(counter.country|| ' ' || counter.continent);
  end if;
   end loop; 
   end; "